# How to make an INNER JOIN with an linked database called by OPENQUERY?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oledb, openquery

I have 2 databases on which I'd like to make an INNER JOIN. But one is on a linked server so I have to call it with OPENQUERY and I don't know how to deal with that.

I've tried to make first the query on my linked database an name it like a local result, and next make tthe INNER JOIN on it but it doesn't seem to work  :

```
SELECT  *
        FROM openquery(myperf_ora, 'SELECT *

            FROM (
            SELECT  EUTRANCELL_ID as Cell_name,
                    TSTAMP,
                    C1526728969 as nb_user

                    FROM VIRTUO.HUA_NUMBER_OF_USER_TAB_V 
                    WHERE TSTAMP BETWEEN ''2019-10-10'' AND ''2019-10-11''
            )
        ') as Test

SELECT  Test.Cell_name,
        [INFO_CELL_N].SITE_THEO,
        [INFO_CELL_N].TECHNO,

        FROM    Test INNER JOIN [KIWI].[dbo].[INFO_CELL_N]
        ON      Test.Cellname = [KIWI].[dbo].[INFO_CELL_N].CELLNAME
```

Doing that I have the following error :

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 57
>   Invalid object name 'Test'.

Note that my OPENQUERY works good and give me that result I need if i do it alone.

I'm rather new using SQL but I assume there is a better way to slove what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Just put the `INNER JOIN` after the first `Select` and you should be good.

Comment: `OPENQUERY` isn't like a CTE; you don't declare it and then reference it in the same statement. `OPENQUERY` forms part of your `FROM`. `SELECT... FROM OPENQUERY('...') AS Test JOIN [KIWI].[dbo].[INFO_CELL_N]...` is what you're after.

Comment: On a different note, don't reference columns using the table's database and schema. You should give `[KIWI].[dbo].[INFO_CELL_N]` an alias (`ICN` seems appropriate) and then use that. Using the schema (and database) name is deprecated when referring to columns; doing so will stop working in a future version and your code won't work anymore.